# Java ArrayList - Return ArrayList

Tags: java, file, io, arraylist

Basically I have two snippets of code. One calls a function that populates and returns an `ArrayList`, but I am having some issues. Here are the two codes:

1. Defining the receiving `ArrayList`, then catching the returning `ArrayList`.

   ArrayList agentArray = new ArrayList<>();
   agentArray = agentListings(strInput);
2. Building the ArrayList then returning it.

   ```
   public static ArrayList agentListings(String strInput) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File(strInput);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        ArrayList<String> agentArray = new ArrayList<>();

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            agentArray.add(in.next());
            in.next();
            in.next();
            in.next();
        }

        Collections.sort(agentArray);
        in.close();
        return agentArray;
    }
   ```

Problem is when I get back to where I am trying to put it into an `ArrayList` once returned, it seems to work fine. But when I try and write it to a file, it throws this error from this code.

```
out.write(agentArray.get(1));
```

I am writing to a file with out being a bufferedwriter which works with simple text and such.

Basically I can't figure out how to write the ArrayList "agentArray" to the file. Any obvious errors am I doing?

==============================================

***EDIT:*** 
Forgot to include the error. When i hover over the `out.write(agentArray.get(1));` the `agentArray` gets underlined in red and the error is

> cannot find symbol  symbol: varible agentArray
>   location: class blabla.blabla

Comment: And the error is? Errors are usually pretty informative you know.

Comment: I am assuming that you want to write the Strings as lines of text in the file? If so, you should be able to make some sort of Reader and Writer to take the strings, and just add them to the text file one by one.

Did you make sure that your arraylist actually got content before you try to write it's contents to the file?

Comment: What's the error and are you really sure that you filled the ArrayList right? Have you controlled the values in it? Try writing out the values in the ArrayList with print.out or control with debugging.

Comment: Why do you initially create a new ArrayList <> (); which is never used, but immediately overwritten with the result of the method call? Where is the out.write located? If it is connected to the returned List, we can't see it from the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error like this:

```
cannot find symbol symbol: varible agentArray
location: class blabla.blabla
```

1)  It is a COMPILATION ERROR, so you shouldn't even try to run your program.

2)  The error message actually tells you what the problem is ... if you think of it from the perspective the compiler.  It is saying this:

> "At this point in the code, I looked for an in-scope declaration of `agentArray`, but I couldn't find one.  I didn't try looking for declarations that are not in scope, because they can't be used, and I can't read your mind ..."

Now, we cannot see exactly where the problem is because you've only shown us snippets, and not the code that relates them.  But you should be able to figure it out, assuming that you understand that basic Java scoping rules.

---

When you post error message, you should cut-and-paste the real error messages, not some abridged / baudlerized / mangled version.  If you want people to take the time to answer, you should take the time to ask properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a type when declaring agentArray outside your method

```
ArrayList<String> agentArray = new ArrayList<>(); agentArray =agentListings(strInput);
```